# Are there always nontrivial primitive elements in a Hopf algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic.  Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra over $k$.  We say $x\in H$ is a primitive element if $\Delta(x)=1\otimes x+x\otimes 1$, where $\Delta$ is the comultiplication in $H$.  The set of primitive elements in $H$, denoted $P(H)$, is a Lie subalgebra, with bracket given by the commutator.

Is $P(H)$ always nontrivial?  If not, what is an example of a Hopf algebra with $P(H)=0$?  What if I require $H$ to be finite-dimensional, or finite-dimensional and local?  Do we have examples of such Hopf algebras with no nontrivial primitive elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no, even when the algebra is finite dimensional. Consider $k = \mathbb C$, and let $H = \mathbb C$ with the usual algebra structure and the comultiplication given by $\Delta(1) = 1 \otimes 1$, hence $\Delta(z) = z (1 \otimes 1)$. The counit is the identity. Then $\mathbb C$ has no nontrivial primitive elements, because $2z = z \implies z = 0$.

For a less trivial example, consider the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}]$ with basis $\langle 1, x \rangle$ ($x$ corresponds to the generator of the cyclic group, $x^2 = 1$). Its coalgebra structure is given by
$$\begin{align}
\Delta(1) & = 1 \otimes 1 & \Delta(x) & = x \otimes x \\
\epsilon(1) &= 1 & \epsilon(x) &= 1
\end{align}$$

Suppose $u = a + bx \in H$ is primitive, where $a,b \in \mathbb C$. Then $\Delta(u) = a (1 \otimes 1) + b (x \otimes x)$ should equal $1 \otimes (a+bx) + (a+bx) \otimes 1$, which is impossible unless $a=b=0$. More generally, I'm almost sure that the group algebra of a finite group has no primitive elements, but I haven't checked all the details yet.

---

However you can still say something in restricted cases. The Milnor–Moore theorem tells you that  a locally conilpotent<sup>*</sup> cocommutative Hopf algebra $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{U}(\mathbb{P}H)$, that is the enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra of primitive elements. So if $\mathbb{P} H = 0$, then $H = 0$.

<sup>*</sup>: Let $\pi : H \to H$ be the projector onto the augmentation ideal $\overline{H}$ of $H$. A Hopf algebra $H$ is said to be locally conilpotent if it can be written as a direct colimit $H = \operatorname{colim} K^m$ such that:

- $\pi^{(n)} \Delta^{(n)}$ is zero when restricted to $K^m$, $m > n$ (this is the iterated coproduct followed by the $n$th tensor power of $\pi$);
- the coproduct restricted to $K^m$ factors through $\operatorname{colim}_{p+q \le m} K^p \otimes K^q \to H \otimes H$.

This is in particular the case when $H$ is a connected Hopf algebra. This is not the case for a group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ with nontrivial $G$: no matter how many times you iterate the coproduct on $g \in G$, none of the factors will ever fall into the augmentation ideal.

For more details about this notion of locally conilpotent and a proof of the Milnor–Moore theorem, I refer you to Benoit Fresse, *Homotopy of Operads and Grothendieck-Teichmüller Groups*, [chapter I.7](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/HopfAlgebras.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

In any group hopf algebra $\mathbb{k}G$ (where $\mathbb{k}$ is a field of characteristic zero), we have a trivial set of primitives:  $P(\mathbb{k}G)=0$, because:
$$
\Delta(\Sigma_{i} k_ig_i)=\Sigma k_i\Delta(g_i)=\Sigma k_ig_i\otimes g_i \neq 1\otimes \Sigma_{i} k_ig_i + \Sigma_{i} k_ig_i \otimes 1 = \Sigma_{i} k_i(1\otimes g_i + g_i \otimes 1)
$$
Note that $\Sigma k_ig_i\otimes g_i$ cannot equal $\Sigma_{i} k_i(1\otimes g_i + g_i \otimes 1)$, due to the fact that $g_i \otimes 1$ and $g_i\otimes g_i$ (for $g_i\neq 1$) are linearly independent in $\mathbb{k}G\otimes\mathbb{k}G$.

And if you want a finite dimensional example, you can always use a finite group $G$.

More generally, it can be shown that:

"*If $H$ is a $\mathbb{k}$-Hopf algebra of finite $\mathbb{k}$-dimension and $\mathbb{k}$ is a field of characteristic zero, then $P(H)=0$*"

The proof of the above fact, amounts to showing -inductively- that, if there is $0\neq x \in P(H)$ then $x^{n}$ (for all positive integers $n$) are linearly independent, which leads us to an obvious contradiction to the finite dimensionality of $H$. Details on the proof can be found for example at [Hopf algebras - an introduction (Dascalescu-Nastasescu-Raianu)](https://books.google.gr/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), exercise 4.2.16, page 174.

Comment: Would you have a proof for this fact?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: I've added some details in my post. By the way, I think that the fact that, in a group Hopf algebra we have no primitives, can also be seen as a corollary of the Cartier-Konstant-Milnor-Moore classification theorem.

Comment: @KonKan, that is true in characteristic zero. The group algebra of the cyclic group of order 2 over a field of characteristic 2 has a nonzero primitive element.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez: thanks for noticing that. I've added the assumption to my post above. And regarding my previous comment, if we are to invoke the Cartier-Konstant-Milnor-Moore classification theorem we should also add that we need an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and a cocommutative hopf algebra.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez: by the way, in the group algebra of the cyclic group of order 2 over a field of characteristic 2, which is -explicitly- its  primitive element ?

Comment: @KonKan the element is $e_1$ or $t$, depending on your notation. The representing algebra is of the form $\mathbb{F}_2[t]/(t^2)$ and the comultiplication on $t$ is $t\mapsto 1\otimes t + t \otimes 1$.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez: I don't think that the group algebra of the cyclic group of order 2 over a field of char. 2 has a nonzero primitive element: Let $C_2=\langle g\rangle$ and let $x=a+bg$ primitive. Hence $a \cdot 1\otimes 1 + b \cdot g\otimes g=\Delta(x)=x\otimes 1 + 1\otimes x= a \cdot 1\otimes 1 + b \cdot g\otimes 1 + a \cdot 1\otimes 1 + b \cdot 1\otimes g = b \cdot g\otimes 1 + b \cdot 1\otimes g$ and by linear independence, $a=b=0$.